# ABAddressBook - multiple address books?

Tags: iphone, contacts, abaddressbook

I am building an app which syncs contacts from an online source. Everything works fine so far...when the phone has one address book:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef group1 = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group1,kABGroupNameProperty,@"Group1",nil);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,group1,nil);
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,nil);

ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
// Edit person values...

ABGroupAddMember(group1,person,nil);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,person,nil);
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,nil);
CFRelease(person);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

The problem occurs, however when the phone already has multiple address books. I am testing on a phone that has one address book for All Contacts, one for Gmail, etc. When I add a contact in the above manner, it adds it to the Gmail address book, and in the process strips the "Group1" identifier from the contact. Is there a way I can change the ABAddressBookRef to point to a specific address book within the phone?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099-CH200-SW7), `ABAddressBookCreate` always returns an address book object populated from the system's address book database.  Which means there is only ever one address book, even if you have multiple instances of `ABAddressBook` that you use to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, you might want to take a look at this post:
[Obtaining Specific ABSource from ABAddressBook in iOS 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679641/obtaining-specific-absource-from-abaddressbook-in-ios-4)

Although I believe Alex is right that there is only ever one address book, that address book may consist of multiple sources (ABSource). And, in iOS 4+ it is possible to specifically identify and manipulate particular sources.